Cómo persistir sesión al recarga página guardando access token en memoria y utilizando refresh token - Angular 18
estoy intentando utilizar access token y refresh token en mi página web hecha con Angular 18 y backEnd en Spring Boot. Necesito ayuda para saber como persistir la sesión del usuario a la hora de recargar la página y que esto no tenga conflicto con el interceptor que estoy manejando (no puedo usar sessionStorage, LocalStorage o cookies).
Para saber si el cliente ya inició sesión lo manejo mediante una variable isLoggedIn que, al ser true, permite que se acceda a las rutas del usuario. Sin embargo, al almacenar el access token en memoria si recargo la página se borra y por ende me saca.
Este es el servicio de auth (El refresh token se guarda automáticamente en las cookies cuando inicio sesión, por eso no envío nada al hacer el refresh)

export class AuthService {

  isLoggedIn = signal<boolean>(false);
  private accessToken:string = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    if (this.getAccessToken()) {
      this.isLoggedIn.update(() => true);
    }
  }

  public login(payload: LoginPayLoad) {
    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.SHA256(payload.pwd).toString();
    const newPayload = {
      ...payload,
      usePassword: hashedPassword,
    };
    return this.http.post<ApiResponse<User>>(`${ApiEndpoint.Auth.Login}`, newPayload, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        if (response && response.Token) {
          console.log('Login exitoso:', response);
          this.setAccessToken(response.Token);
          console.log("access token:" + this.getAccessToken());
          this.isLoggedIn.update(() => true);
        }
        return response;
      })
    );
  }

  public getRefreshToken() {
    return this.http.post<ApiResponse<User>>(`${ApiEndpoint.Auth.Refresh}`, null).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response && response.NewAccessToken) {
          this.setAccessToken(response.NewAccessToken);
          return response.NewAccessToken;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Hubo un error al generar el nuevo token");
        }
      })
    );
  }

  setAccessToken(token:string) {
    this.accessToken = token;
  }

  getAccessToken() {
    return this.accessToken;
  }

}


asimismo, estoy utilizando un interceptor (ya verifiqué que funciona) que me permite renovar el access token en caso de la expiración del mismo.
Este es el interceptor
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, switchMap, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { LocalStorage } from '../constants.ts/constants';

export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

   if (req.url.includes('/login') || req.url.includes('/register')) {
    return next(req);
  }

 if (req.url.includes('/refresh')) {
  const refreshReq = req.clone({
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return next(refreshReq);
  }

  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const token = authService.getAccessToken();

  const authReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });

  return next(authReq).pipe(
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
        return authService.getRefreshToken().pipe(
          switchMap((newToken:string) =>{
            authService.setAccessToken(newToken);
            const retriedReq = req.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${newToken}`
              }
            })
            return next(retriedReq);
          }
          )
        )
      }
      return throwError(() => err);
    })
  );

};


Ya he intentando con observables (no logré mucho ya que recién estoy empezando a usar angular) en el app.component y una función que verifica si el usuario tiene la sesión iniciada. Sin embargo, esta función me generaba problemas con los headers (el protegido y el que pueden ver todos) entonces la descarté
Función de verificar sesión
 async verifySession() {
    try {
      const response = await firstValueFrom(this.getRefreshToken());
      if (response && response.NewAccessToken) {
        this.setAccessToken(response.NewAccessToken);
        this.isLoggedIn.update(() => true);
      } else {
        this.logout();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.logout();
    }
  } 

Perdón si me falta algo, es mi segunda vez usando esto.

"No puedo usar sessionStorage, LocalStorage o cookies". En alguna parte debe guardarse. Lo que pides no es posible.
